# Neural Net not able to learn simple analytical equation

Tags: neural-network, pytorch

I am currently making my first attempts with Pytorch. I am trying to solve a simple equation with a neural net. Analytically solved, the result of my neural net shall look like this:
$$
y = \frac{x_5}{x_2} - \frac{x_1-x_2}{2 x_3 x_4}\frac{x_2}{x_1} 
$$
while I am randomly generating input data with the following boundaries: $$500 \leq x_1 \leq 1000 \\ 1 \leq x_2 \leq x_1 \\ 1 \leq x_5 \leq 10000 \\ 1e-6\leq x_4 \leq 1e-3 \\ 1000 \leq x_3 \leq 50000 $$
Now the neural network does not seem to be able to learn the function. I assume this is due to the large spreads of the input areas of the function. I have already tried it with various network architectures and different activation functions. I have also tried an lr scheduler and varied the learning rate from 1e-2-1e-8. I have also tried to summarize the input variables $x_3x_4$ as a separate variable.

Since I would like to add additional equations to that neural network to be solved later on, I implemented the following, normalized, loss function:

```
F.l1_loss((y_est+(x_1-x_2)/(2*x_3*x_4)*x_2/x_1 - x_5/x_2)/(x_5/x_2),torch.FloatTensor(np.zeros(batch_size)))
```

I mainly worked here with nn of multiple sizes and layers, but couldnt get good results (mainly losses over 0.5, but bouncing up to 4ish)

Thanks in advance.

Edit:

```
import torch.optim as optim
import numpy as np
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
import random
from torch.optim.lr_scheduler import ReduceLROnPlateau

def get_batch(batch_size=32):
    batch_x = []
    for i in range(batch_size):
        x_1 = random.uniform(500,1000)
        x_2 = random.uniform(1,x_1-1)
        x_3 = random.uniform(1,10000)
        x_4 = random.uniform(1e-6,0.001)
        x_5 = np.random.randint(1000,50000)
        batch_x.append([x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5])
    return torch.FloatTensor(batch_x).cuda().contiguous()

class CustomNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self,n_input,n_output,n_hidden_neurons,n_hidden_layers):
        super(CustomNet, self).__init__()
        self.sequential_layers = nn.Sequential(
          *((nn.Linear(n_input,n_hidden_neurons),)+ tuple(nn.Linear(n_hidden_neurons,n_hidden_neurons) for i in range(n_hidden_layers)))
        )
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(n_hidden_neurons,n_output)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = torch.log(x)
        output = self.sequential_layers(x)
        output = torch.exp(output)
        output = self.fc1(output)
        return output

batch_size = 1000
n_epochs = 50000
n_input,n_output,n_hidden_neurons,n_hidden_layers = 5,1,16,1

# create model
nnet = CustomNet(n_input,n_output,n_hidden_neurons,n_hidden_layers)
nnet = nnet.to("cuda")

lr, counter = 0.01, 0
optimizer = optim.Adam(nnet.parameters(),lr=lr)
target = torch.FloatTensor(np.zeros(batch_size)).contiguous().cuda()
lr_scheduler = ReduceLROnPlateau(optimizer, mode='min', factor=0.1, patience=1000, verbose=True)
target = torch.FloatTensor(np.zeros(batch_size)).cuda().contiguous()
for i in range(n_epochs):

    # Reset gradients
    nnet.zero_grad()

    batch_x = get_batch(batch_size)
    x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5 = batch_x.T
    y_est = nnet(batch_x)
    y_est = y_est[:,0]
    output = F.l1_loss((y_est+(x_1-x_2)/(2*x_3*x_4)*x_2/x_1 - x_5/x_2)/(x_5/x_2),target)

    # Backward pass
    loss = output.item()
    output.backward()
    optimizer.step()
    lr_scheduler.step(output)
```

Comment: Have you tried first overfitting on just some training samples? Additionally, it would help if you could provide a full code example (i.e. generating the training data as well as creating and training the model) as this would help us better diagnose any possible issues.

Comment: I've updated the question with a code example. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of suggestions:

- add nonlinearity between hidden layers and increase the number of hidden layers: currently `self.sequential_layers` is just a stacked linear transformation. Add ReLU between consecutive hidden layer should help you learn quicker;
- not sure if `torch.log` and `torch.exp` is a good idea. You may remove the `torch.log` and replace `torch.exp` with your choice of nonlinearity for bridging the hidden layers;
- use smaller batch sizes: say 64 or 128.